# How to delete NSMutableDictionary with key in NSMutableArray in swift 3

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Below mentioned is my array of coupons and I want to delete dictionary which contains 'x' code

```
    (
        {
        "coupon_code" = FLAT20PERCENT;
    }
       {
       “coupon_code” = FLAT5PERCENT;
    }
       {
      “coupon_code” = FLAT50;
    }
   )
```

Comment: You can get the `dictionary` which contains 'x' code using an `NSPredicate`. Then delete that object from your array. @Rajat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, why don't you try using Swift's [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array) and [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary) structures over their `NS` counterparts? This will make your job much easier and look your code more concise:

Objective-C way:

```
let array = NSMutableArray(array: [
  NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["coupon_code": "FLAT50PERCENT"]),
  NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["coupon_code": "FLAT5PERCENT"]),
  NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["coupon_code": "FLAT50"])
])
```

Swift way:

*(Plus, you don't lose the type unlike above.)*

```
var array = [
  ["coupon_code": "FLAT50PERCENT"],
  ["coupon_code": "FLAT5PERCENT"],
  ["coupon_code": "FLAT50"]
]
```

Anyway, if you insist on using collection classes from Objective-C, here is one way of doing that:

```
let searchString = "PERCENT"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "coupon_code contains[cd] %@", searchString)
// change it to "coupon_code == @" for checking equality.

let indexes = array.indexesOfObjects(options: []) { (dictionary, index, stop) -> Bool in
  return predicate.evaluate(with: dictionary)
}
array.removeObjects(at: indexes)
```

You can download the playground from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32i0gefxlvhmalf/AADoxkWhgP8CtWwrkrTFMbrAa?dl=0).

Comment: Skip the `NSPredicate`, put the condition in the block.

Answer (score -1):

Try using below code, this may solve your problem. For any clarification feel free to leave a comment. :)

```
    //Creating an `NsPredicate` that helps to find out the dictionary which contains 'x' code.
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "coupon_code == %@", x)

    //Filtering your array with the pred to get that Dictionary.
    let dict = array .filtered(using: pred)

    //Deleting that object from your array.
    array .removeObject(identicalTo: dict)
```

Comment: Can someone please tell me where I am wrong so that I can rectify myself and never give any wrong answer that will get down voted. Please clarify. :)

Comment: `array .filtered(using: pred)` won't compile. `array.filtered(using: pred)` returns an array, not a dictionary. I usually try the code myself before I post an answer. And sometimes even good questions and answers are downvoted.

Comment: So if i do like `let dict =array.filtered(using: pred)[0]`, will that be correct? @Willeke